# Android findViewById method not resolved///TextView problems

Tags: android, class, textview, android-context

I am creating an engine for a game, and I want to have an activity that displays all the statistics that I will want to know in one simple screen. Here is my code:

```
public class StatAct extends Screen {
public StatAct(Game game){super(game);
}

public void update(float deltaTime) {
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.screenText);
    textView.setText("Screen Width: " + HandleRenderView.screenW + ", Screen Height: " + HandleRenderView.screenH);

}
```

And my Screen code:

```
public abstract class Screen {
protected final Game game;

public Screen(Game game){
    this.game=game;
}

public abstract void update(float deltaTime);
public abstract void present(float deltaTime);
public abstract void pause();
public abstract void resume();
public abstract void dispose();
}
```

How can I get the Context to make a new TextView(this)? And also, when I try to use the findViewById(R.id.screenText); it says that the method findViewById is not resolved. I've tried restarting Android Studio, Rebuild the application, and even clean it. Nothing has helped.

EDIT:: I've also had to import the R file to just get the R.id.screenText variable. That was also a problem, and I do not see why I needed to import it when it should just be accessible as it always has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findViewById` in Activity or inflate a layout and then use the view like `view.findViewById`.

In your case `StatAct` is not a `Activtiy` class. `findViewById` is a method of `Activity` class.

You can pass context to the constructor of a non-activity class. But i am not sure what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks to you, I thought of adding a custom getContext() method, that returns the context of the Activity class I have. Making it public and static, I am able to pass it along. Atleast without errors. I'm going to test it now.

Comment: I am trying to get a Class that extends SurfaceView, on the method setSurfaceSize(int x, int y) to public static int screenW, screenH. I am trying to pass those variables into that TextView to display the size of the screen. I have tried, but it says it has to be >0...But I think I have to run that thread for it to become valid.

Comment: @Azurai you need to re-think your design

Comment: Yeah I bailed on the TextView idea, and went with the paint and canvas.drawText() method. That is still giving me trouble, so I tried to draw a bitmap on the screen and the scaling variable is turning up zero. So I got to find that problem out now.

Comment: you can draw text on canvas

Comment: Yeah and I got it to work. My problem was my scaling from from the actual screen resolution/800 was coming out to be zero. I forgot to add the (double): double scaleWidth=(double)framebuffer.getWidth()/800; So now I have it all working. Just messing around adding new code for FPS, music, sounds, and stuff. Thanks man!